# Best way to use a different PROD config file (.js) on GitHub pages?

Tags: github, configuration, github-pages

I've searched around quite a bit but can't seem to find an answer.

I just started using GitHub pages about a month ago and am still trying to figure it out.

In the past, my "commit to master" step was always different than my "deploy to PROD" step.

But now, with GitHub Pages, they seem to be the same thing, which confuses me.

I have a static html/js site. I am using the Adobe Viewer SDK which needs different client Ids. One for my GitHub Pages and one for my localhost.  I include a different 'config.js' depending on which env I am in.

My current workflow is:

1. git add .
2. git reset config.js
3. git commit -m "Blah blah blah"
4. git push origin master

How do I improve my workflow to not have to reset 'config.js' each time?

**I don't want to use Jekyll.** (Too heavy; I'm trying to be as lightweight as possible.)

I am currently on the verge of writing a PowerShell script that wraps my git commits to automate my workflow better to exclude my 'config.js' every time I commit. But, *surely*, there's a better way to do this. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this quick PowerShell script worked for me:

```
# Friday - June 19, 2020
# Only run me from "C:\code\project_root" !!!

param([string]$m = "m", [string]$testflag = "testing flag")

Write-Host "Commit message: '$($m)'"
Write-Host $testflag

Invoke-Expression "git add ."
Invoke-Expression "git reset config.js"
Invoke-Expression "git commit -m '$($m)'"
Invoke-Expression "git push origin master"
```